# Как сделать скрипт посредством винды который мог постучать на сайт не открывая его

Tags: windows, bat, vbscript

Что бы он постучал на сайт скажем https://mysite.ru/file.php запустил тем самым .php и все) Но нужно это сделать так чтобы никаких окон на компе не открывалось.
Есть готовый вариант но через bat где открывается консолька тем самым мешая пользователям работать=(

```js
Готовый 

    @if (@This==@IsBatch) @then
@echo off
rem **** batch zone *********************************************************

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Batch file will delegate all the work to the script engine 
    if not "%~1"=="" (
        wscript //E:JScript "%~dpnx0" %1
    )

    rem End of batch area. Ensure batch ends execution before reaching
    rem javascript zone
    exit /b

@end

var http = WScript.CreateObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0');
var url = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)

    http.open("GET", url, false);
    http.send();

    WScript.Quit(0);
```

Comment: Можно по какому-то триггеру запустить сервер на node.js и отправить xhr запрос, но это просто мысли вслух, слишком громоздко

Comment: Скачать `wget`.
`wget https://mysite.ru/file.php`

Answer (score 3):

> Есть готовый вариант но через bat где открывается консолька тем самым
>   мешая пользователям работать=(

Эту проблему можно решить, если добавить Bat'ник в "Расписание выполнения задач" и там указать какую-то другую учетку. В итоге, пользователь не будет видеть консольку.

Comment: Добавил готовый, но касяк в том что не всегда даже учетки всех администраторов присутствую на сервере, и ошибки иногда начинает флудить, а пока так и реализовано как ты посоветовал) + ссылку на сайт берет из ключа запуска файла

Comment: так что вариант не очень подходящий(

Answer (score 0):

Скрытый запуск организуется в Windows Script Host помощью метода run.
Второй параметр - intWindowStyle - чтобы скрыть задачу.
Создайте vbs-скрипт и запускайте, что пожелаете без графических окон или окон консоли.

P.S.
Если поискали, то давно нашли бы ответ: 
[Hide command prompt window when using Exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297699/)